# How resumes reading from USB virtual com after client reset?

Tags: usb, serial, c#

I have dotnet-core app on raspberry pi 4, which reading data from USB serial port (virtual com) from STM-Microcontroller board.
When I reset the STM-board, the pi stop receiving data !

How can I resume reading data after STM-board reset ?

Comment: you wait for the STM board to start sending again ... it appears that you have not included all information in your post ... as a result, your question makes no sense

Comment: Without the code its impossible to assist.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reset the board, the USB connection is broken as if the device was yanked out of the port.  When the board comes back online, initializing the port is under the control of the STM board.  The usb client firmware on the board may affect this process.

On the pi side of the usb connection, the old serial port will be disconnected, and the USB hotplug mechanisms will establish a new serial port as if a new device was plugged in.

Your application on the pi must release the old port and find the new one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your solution is exactly what I need, but on pi side how can I detect this disconnection? (what is the best way to detect it?)

Comment: I'm not sure how dotnet-core handles this, but in linux, reads would fail or return zero bytes, and you may also get an EOF indicator.  Writes would also fail, possibly more violently.  There would also be out of band hotplug events.